# Preserve message order on redelivery in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jboss, jms, sequence, activemq-artemis

I am new to JMS. We are using JBoss EAP 7.3 with the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis as our broker.  We have a queue where it is critical that the messages be processed in the order they were placed into the queue.

I have the queue setup with a `max-delivery-attempts` set to `-1` and `redelivery-delay` set to `10000` milliseconds.  I have a single consumer reading from the queue. As long as there are no errors, everything works as expected and the messages all process in sequence.

In case of an error, the message is scheduled for redelivery with a delay of 10 seconds. Unfortunately the consumer then goes on to process the next message which causes them to be processed out of sequence.

I thought this might be a prefetch issue but I don't believe it is. I tried configuring the `consumer-window-size` to `0` effectively turning off any prefetching by the consumer. I also tested by sending a message that would fail, as the only message in the queue. I waited for it to fail and to be scheduled for redelivery in 10 seconds.  Nothing should have been prefetched by the consumer at that point. I then sent a second message and the consumer received and processed it while the first message was still waiting for redelivery.

Ironically I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397532/activemq-artemis-redelivery-delay) where someone using ActiveMQ "Classic" (not ActiveMQ Artemis) is getting the default behavior that I want / expected our of ActiveMQ Artemis. That is if a message is redelivered, subsequent messages wait until the redelivery of the first message occurs.

Is there anyway to get this behavior in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redelivery from queue is unordered in ActiveMQ Artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318890/redelivery-from-queue-is-unordered-in-activemq-artemis)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as a work-around.  I set the redelivery-delay to 0 and implemented a consumer side sleep to prevent the same message being consumed over and over again very rapidly.   There is a negative side effect.  The message that's causing the problem will always be "in-delivery" and cannot be removed from the queue.  If our support group decides the message can be discarded without causing an issue, it will require them to shutdown the deployment (which includes dozens of other queue consumers on different queues) to be able to remove that message.

Comment: That does answer my question though.  It's unfortunate that Artemis does not support this use-case.   ActiveMQ (not Artemis) supports both scenarios (blocking and non-blocking redeliveries) which seems very sensible. 

While I'm not very happy about the answer, at least I know to stop searching the documentation for solution that simply isn't there.  So I do appreciate that.  This is the second time you've helped me on an JMS issue.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would _strongly_ encourage you to set a `max-delivery-attempts` to something other than `-1` and set a `dead-letter-address`. Whether redelivery is blocking or non-blocking a `max-delivery-attempts` of `-1` will require administrative intervention to deal with a problematic message which is usually not desirable in a production situation. Also, instead of shutting down the deployment you can try simply invoking `pause()` on the queue via the management API, dealing with the message, and then invoking `resume()`.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken the blocking redelivery behavior is a feature of the OpenWire JMS _client_ shipped with ActiveMQ "Classic." ActiveMQ Artemis deals with redelivery strictly on the broker so it applies consistently to all supported protocols. If you _really_ want blocking redelivery you should be able to just use the OpenWire JMS client.

Comment: Thanks for the input Justin.  We do JIT / Sequencing logistics for automotive manufacturers building vehicles on a line moving in real time.   Their legacy systems (which used to send messages over serial cables) send us messages in a very specific and important sequence that must 100% be maintained exactly.  Downtime is back-charged at thousands of dollars per minute.  Sending a message to a DLQ would, by definition cause an out-of-sequence problem. If a poison message is encountered it must be dealt with immediately by our support staff before any other messages can process.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change your broker. I was merely pointing out that you can change the _client_ to get blocking redelivery. In any event, all management APIs are proprietary because JMS doesn't define a management API of its own. There's no way to avoid that. Even the ability to configure the number of delivery attempts or redelivery delay is not covered by the JMS spec.

Comment: The middleware is chosen by a our middleware team. I, unfortunately cannot choose a different broker or client. They prefer JBoss EAP and the services it provides. I may look into using the Artemis API to pause the queue when we encounter a poison message. I really hate using any proprietary broker APIs.

Comment: Sorry yes, I just realized you said client and not broker so I changed my comment.  But yeah, either way we are pretty constrained in those respects.  I think pausing the queue using the Artemis API and alerting our support staff is the best option.  Sorry I don't mean to sound like I'm complaining (but obviously I am).  Literally the definition of the word "queue" references sequence...  so it astounds me that maintaining sequence seems to be nearly impossible in Artemis without addressing it in my own code somehow.  OK rant over, back to coffee and code.  Thank you again very much Justin!